# How to convert XML data (Which was retrieved from a link) into a byte like object?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, xml-parsing

I am new here in StackOverflow and recently started web scraping using python.
As the question stated, I can't convert XML data which I retrieved from a link into a byte like object.

I guess I retrieved the XML data all right(picture 1).
But, Whenever I am trying to convert it into a tree, an error is occurring and saying **"a bytes-like object is required"** (Picture 2)

**Code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import ssl


# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup)

#tree = ET.fromstring(soup)
#print(tree)
#for i in soup:
#  print('Name:', tree.find('name').text)
#  print('Attr:', tree.find('comments').text)
```

**Input Link:** http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml

Picture -1 [Code is running fine after retrieving the data from the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otyuh.png)

Picture -2 [Error is occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsksY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the contents of the url itself. And, actually, you don't really need `bs4` but you might want to look into `xmltodict`module.

Try this:

```
import xmltodict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib.request import urlopen


html = urlopen("http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml").read()
tree = ET.fromstring(html)
print(xmltodict.parse(html)['commentinfo']['note'])
```

Output:

```
This file contains the sample data for testing
```

EDIT: Based on your approach here's how to loop over the tree elements

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib.request import urlopen


html = urlopen("http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml").read()

tree = ET.fromstring(html)

for item in tree.iter():
    if item.tag == "name":
        print(f"{item.tag}: {item.text.strip()}")
```

The `fromstring()` method converts the Element to an ElementTree and that allows us to iterate over all nodes with the `iter()` method.

This outputs:

```
name: Romina
name: Laurie
name: Bayli
name: Siyona
name: Taisha
name: Alanda
...
```

You can also access specific elements by calling the `findall()` method. For example, to get all the names do this:

```
names = tree.findall(".//name")
print([name.text for name in names])
```

Output:

```
['Romina', 'Laurie', 'Bayli', 'Siyona', 'Taisha', 'Alanda', 'Ameelia'...]
```

Comment: brother, The soup part was already printing before (Check picture -1).
Problem is, I can't print the tree part. (Check picture-2)
The same problem is still occurring at your code. Still, a byte like object is being required :(

Comment: This worked this time, Thank u very much, brother. :D 
I made it upto 7th line "tree" on my own in the past but the rest of the part is completely new to me as I'm new to XML! 

Can u explain me the last 3 lines please?

Comment: This I understood, Thank u very much! :D